# NodeJs server side framework for big application concerning social media

Tags: node.js, api, web-applications, frameworks, sails.js

NodeJs server side framework for big application concerning **social media**.

I used to program mainly in PHP, with Yii as my favorite framework. Because I'm going to start a big project concerning social media interaction (a website like Facebook), I decided to use nodeJS at the server side. What framework (server side) should I use?

### Requirements:

- I like the MVC structure with data validation and policies/rights;
- Framework should be (kind of) stable;
- active and (big) community;
- good Socket.io support because of android app;
- probably only as server side framework, to create an API. Client side AngularJS *(by Google)* or telephone app which uses the api data;
- (quick)

### Some of the options:

- Sails (Tried it, community too small and framework is not finished (my opinion)).
- Meteor
- towerJs
- DerbyJs

Thank you so much for your time and expertise!

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you use **Express with Passport plugin**, and avoid Meteor and derby.

- There are a lot of express derivatives - so new people can benefit from all great things about the specific framework - use heavier one like Geddy but then drop down to express for more detail work.
- Why avoid meteor - it is a closed ecosystem, and great for prototyping, but does not meet strong community. 
  Similar reasons for meteor.
- My personal architectural style is to boost privacy by having smart clients with JS only and with server side only accessed for personalization, monetization, analytics, etc. This way offline access is all enabled with this. Meteor, Derby, etc. all pretty much insist on 100% web access. Going forward building eg mobile apps is really hard with them.
- Passport is one of the great features of node (and express) I have built Social Networking niche sites with PHP, MySQL, and the biggest hurdle for social media is getting / aggregating across so many sites that have totally different APIs. The biggest hurdle to starting is unique variations on OAUTH2 implementations.
- Don't really know about Sails or Tower. But that is also saying why go with express or derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!/) another look; I think the concerns in your question are now outdated. The community is huge and still growing, it's still based on the familiarity of express and now supports over a dozen databases.